# Error 1215: no se puede agregar llave foranea MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando hacer unos Foreign Key a unas tablas que he creado pero MySQL no me permite, estas son las tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE publicador(id_publicador INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
                        fecha_publicador TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                                         ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                        nombre_publicador VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                        apellido_publicador VARCHAR(20),
                        ubicacion_carrito VARCHAR(50),
                        horario_publicador VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
                        jornada_publicador TIME);

CREATE TABLE carrito(id_carrito INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
                     fecha_carrito TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                                   ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                     ubicacion_carrito VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE horario(id_horario INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
                     fecha_horario TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                                   ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                     turno_horario VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE jornada(id_horario INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
                     fecha_jornada TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                                   ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                     dia_jornada TIME NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE jornada(id_jornada INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
                     fecha_jornada TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                                   ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                     dia_jornada TIME NOT NULL);
```

Y los siguientes son los foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE publicador
   ADD CONSTRAINT fk_publicador_horario
   FOREIGN KEY (horario_publicador)
   REFERENCES horario (turno_horario)
   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE publicador
   ADD CONSTRAINT fk_publicador_jornada
   FOREIGN KEY (jornada_publicador)
   REFERENCES jornada (dia_jornada)
   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Las tablas se crean correctamente, pero a la hora de aplicar los foreign key da el error de que no se pueden aplicar las llaves foráneas.

Answer (score 4):

El error sucede porque la columna a la que la clave foránea apunta no está indexada. Ese es el requisito mínimo para que se pueda definir una clave foránea con éxito.

Por ejemplo, si creas el índice siguiente:

```
create index idx_horario_turno_horario on horario(turno_horario);
```

...verás que ahora puedes crear la clave foránea siguiente con éxito:

```
ALTER TABLE publicador
   ADD CONSTRAINT fk_publicador_horario
   FOREIGN KEY (horario_publicador)
   REFERENCES horario (turno_horario)
   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Pero, aunque esto arregle tu problema immediato, sería bueno preguntarse si en realidad deberías definir la clave foránea usando esas columnas. Los más *normal* es que una clave foránea apunte hacia una clave primaria o única.

Por eso, tal vez sería mejor redefinir las columnas en tu tabla `publicador` para que apunten a las claves primarias de las tablas `horario` y `jornada`.

Ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE publicador(id_publicador INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
                        fecha_publicador TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                                         ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                        nombre_publicador VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                        apellido_publicador VARCHAR(20),
                        ubicacion_carrito VARCHAR(50),
                        id_horario INT NOT NULL, -- cambiar aquí
                        id_jornada INT);        -- y aquí
```

... y luego definir las claves foráneas de esta manera:

```
ALTER TABLE publicador
   ADD CONSTRAINT fk_publicador_horario
   FOREIGN KEY (id_horario)
   REFERENCES horario (id_horario)
   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE publicador
   ADD CONSTRAINT fk_publicador_jornada
   FOREIGN KEY (id_jornada)
   REFERENCES jornada (id_jornada)
   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Pero, por supuesto, todo depende de qué representan las diferentes columnas. Yo solo estoy asumiendo al hacer esta recomendación, pero tu sabrás que es lo mejor en este caso.

Comment: se que me recomiendas poner los id de las columnas de las tablas dependientes de `publicador` pero esto no sería un mal diseño de una base de datos, además otra cosa, una columna puede tener varias llaves foráneas?, de esta forma haría alusión a las llaves primarias de las otras columnas a partir de la llave primaria de `publicador`.

Comment: Al contrario, usar los id de las columnas de las tablas dependientes de `publicador` es buen diseño y es lo usual. Una de las razones por la que es buena idea es que evita repetir valores en mas de una tabla, que iría en contra de los principios de normalización de base de datos. En cuanto a la segunda parte de tu comentario, me disculpas pero no entiendo lo que quieres decir.

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es que en dado caso una columna pudiera tener varios constraint pues pudiera hacer las referencias a partir del `primary key` de la tabla **publicador** , porque en esos campos pienso poner información y si los repito tendría que cambiarles el tipo de dato a **varchar**, ahí pues pierdo la posibilidad del **foreign key**

Comment: Disculpa, aun no entiendo del todo. Creo que necesitaría ver un ejemplo concreto de lo que dices para evaluar bien la pregunta. Tal vez valga la pena abrir una nueva pregunta al respecto, permitiendo así que otros vean la pregunta.

Comment: Necesito las columnas `horario_publicador` y `jornada_publicador` de la tabla `publicador` pues debo poner información en la primera en **varchar** y en la segunda necesito introducir horas y minutos por eso esta **time** si repito las mismas columnas de las llaves primerias de las tablas **horario** y **jornada** tendré que dejarlas con el mismo valor **`int`** y no podré introducir las informaciones pertinentes a estas por eso necesito dejarlas con los valores que tienen actualmente **varchar** y **time**, no se si me puedes comprender ahora.

Comment: Si deseas cambiar el horario o jornada para un publicador, lo normal sería ajustando el valor para `id_horario` o `id_jornada` en la tabla `publicador` para apuntar al registro adecuado de las tablas `horario` o `jornada`. En otras palabras, no veo porque necesitas *insertar* información texto de jornada u horario en la tabla `publicador`. Para eso están las tablas `jornada` y `horario`. La tabla `publicador` debería limitarse a apuntar al registro adecuado de esas tablas. Y para hacer eso, solo necesitas valores que apunten a las claves primarias de esas 2 tablas.

Comment: Entonces los recupero con un Inner Join, quizás podríamos continuar hablando el chat que dices

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49827/discussion-between-david-calderon-and-sstan).