# MySQL - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

**Tengo estas dos tablas y una consulta sobre ella.**

Tabla clientes:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes (
    email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, 
    nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    apellidos VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    dni VARCHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    telefono VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    direccion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ciudad VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO clientes (email, nombre, apellidos, dni, telefono, direccion, ciudad) VALUES 
("pablo2345@hotmail.com", "PABLO", "GOMEZ SUAREZ", "13245764V", "654789222", "CALLE LA VERDE", "GAMA");
```

Tabla cpostales:

```
CREATE TABLE cpostales (
    cpostal VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    ciudad VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ciudad) REFERENCES clientes(ciudad)
);

INSERT INTO cpostales (cpostal, ciudad) VALUES 
("39740", "SANTOÑA"),
("39790", "GAMA");
```

**¿Por qué me dice que no puede añadir la clave foránea?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como resultado final quisiera, por ejemplo, al realizar una consulta que me muestre el código postal de la ciudad del cliente.
Por ejemplo:

- Consulta:

> Selección de nombre, ciudad, cpostal de todos los clientes que sean de "Gama".

```
SELECT clientes.nombre, clientes.ciudad, cpostales.cpostal FROM clientes, cpostales WHERE clientes.ciudad = "GAMA" AND clientes.ciudad=cpostales.ciudad
```

**¿Éste sería el resultado de la consulta?**

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error 1215: no se puede agregar llave foranea MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38304/error-1215-no-se-puede-agregar-llave-foranea-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efectivamente, como te recomienda @AgustinG, creando un índice en `clientes.ciudad`, lo resuelves:

```
ALTER TABLE clientes ADD INDEX(ciudad);
```

Para la consulta que quieres realizar, aunque la tuya con producto cartesiano es válida, te recomiendo un producto interno, que es mucho más eficiente:

```
SELECT nombre,ciudad,cpostal 
  FROM clientes JOIN cpostales USING(ciudad)
  WHERE clientes.ciudad='GAMA';
```

Aunque, para buscar el CP de un cliente, no busques por su ciudad, sino por su email o nombre. Si vas a buscar por ciudad, busca directamente en `cpostales` y no será necesario que vincules dos tablas.

Y, ya por último, no podrás insertar el registro de `SANTOÑA` en `cpostales`, porque no aún no tienes en `clientes` ningún registro de esa bonita localidad cántabra.

**Relación entre clave ajena y producto interno**

Ten en cuenta que un producto interno (`INNER JOIN`) no es lo mismo que una clave ajena (`FK`). De hecho se utilizan en contextos totalmente diferentes:

- `INNER JOIN`: es un vínculo temporal con la intención de combinar la información de dos tablas conforme al criterio definido en el `ON`
- `FK`: es una restricción que impide registrar un dato en una tabla si previamente no existe en otra. Que, además, requiere que el campo en la tabla referenciada esté indexado. De ahí que sea necesario crear ese índice.

Si simplemente necesitas combinar tablas, no necesitas la clave ajena y, en consecuencia, tampoco necesitas crear el índice.

Tal vez hayas pensado así porque Access, cuando has establecido previamente una clave ajena (que denomina relación), te facilita las consultas presuponiendo un `INNER JOIN` entre esas dos tablas. Pero son dos cosas diferentes.

Comment: Funciona sí, pero pensé que uniendo las claves (ciudad) de ambas tablas se vincularían y las tablas serían relacionadas, sin utilizar un index.

Comment: Te amplío la respuesta para aclararte esa confusión